# Php, get key value based on another key/value pair?

Tags: php, key

How does one search as an example for EndDate = 2019-05-31 and get the corresponding Id value?

```
{
    "Data": [{
        "Id": "xxx",
        "StartDate": "2017-06-01",
        "EndDate": "2018-05-31"
    }, {
        "Id": "af7fb21b-3477-4d87-a0dc-3780ef2b39dd",
        "StartDate": "2018-06-01",
        "EndDate": "2019-05-31"
    }]
}
```

Comment: One would either loop over the data oneself and check if the end date of the current item is the one one’s looking for, or one would go check what array functions PHP has on offer and which one(s) could be suitable for the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array_column to create a array with "EndDate" => "Id" pairs. Then have you a direct access to your Id if your key exists.

```
<?php
$arrayKeyValue = array_column($array['Data'],'Id','EndDate');

echo $arrayKeyValue["2019-05-31"]; 
//af7fb21b-3477-4d87-a0dc-3780ef2b39dd
```

Answer (score 0):

- First, use [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to filter `EndDate` values.
- Second, you can use [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to get it's index.
- Third, use this index in the original array and access `Id` key.

**Code:**

```
<?php

$index = array_search('2019-05-31',array_column($data['Data'],'EndDate'));

echo $data['Data'][$index]['Id'];
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/b4aAA

Answer (score 0):

This is basic method not using special array methods.

```
$json = '[{
        "Id": "xxx",
        "StartDate": "2017-06-01",
        "EndDate": "2018-05-31"
    }, {
        "Id": "af7fb21b-3477-4d87-a0dc-3780ef2b39dd",
        "StartDate": "2018-06-01",
        "EndDate": "2019-05-31"
    },{
        "Id": "af7fb21b-3477-4d87-a0dc-3780ef2b49dd",
        "StartDate": "2018-09-12",
        "EndDate": "2018-06-30"
    }]';

  $data = json_decode($json,true);

  $enddate = '2019-05-31';

  foreach($data as $k => $v){
      if($v['EndDate'] == $enddate){
         $res[] = array(
             'Id' => $v['Id'],
             'StartDate' => $v['StartDate'],
             'EndDate' => $v['EndDate']
             );
      }

  }

  print_r($res[0]['Id']);  // af7fb21b-3477-4d87-a0dc-3780ef2b39dd
```